# Do I lose a degree of freedom if there is a restriction on the explanatory variables?

Tags: multiple-regression, degrees-of-freedom, restrictions

In a linear model the degrees of freedom are (if there is an intercept) $df = n - k - 1$. So in the following interaction model the degrees of freedom would be $n - 7 - 1$

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + \beta_4 x_1:z + \beta_5 x_2:z + \beta_6 x_3:z + \epsilon$$

If I then put constraints on the explanatory variable, for example that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$, do I lose a degree of freedom as one of the terms is not free to vary anymore due to this constraint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By introducing a constraint, you would normally *gain* a degree of freedom, since there are fewer free parameters to be estimated. In your case, you would have to omit one of the variables (e.g. $x_3$) from the model to prevent perfect multicollinearity, and you would no longer have to estimate $\beta_3$ and $\beta_6$. So you would actually gain two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Is the gain of degrees of freedom due to constraints from a theorem?

Comment: @Galen It's an immediate consequence of the standard theorems about dimensions of vector spaces in linear algebra.  There is an implicit assumption, though: that the original design matrix is of full rank (in other words, there aren't already some constraints introduced by the pattern of observations of the independent variables).